# nodejs request.post (user, pass) and get data from another url after auth

Tags: node.js, authentication, request

I want to get some data that are available after authentication. I pass through a post login and password on the page http://site.domain.com/auth.html and I want to get html from another page http://site.domain.com/anotherpage.html

```
request.post({followAllRedirects: true, url:'http://site.domain.com/auth.html', form:{user:'login@domain.com', pass:'password'}},
function (error, response, body) {
    if (!error) {
        request('http://site.domain.com/anotherpage.html', function(error, response, html){
           fs.appendFileSync('log.txt', html, encoding='utf8');
        });
    }
});
```

Authentication takes place normally (there is a message in the html with greeting), after request I get the data as if the authentication is not passed.

fixed result:

```
var j = request.jar(); var request = request.defaults({jar:j});
```

and then my code

Answer (score 0):

Most often than not, in the web, authentication information is store as cookies in the user's browser. Because this is a server request, I don't think two "unrelated" requests is going to cut it, as no header information pertaining to the first request is being sent along with the second request. Perhaps you could try [this](https://www.haykranen.nl/2011/06/21/basic-http-authentication-in-node-js-using-the-request-module/) strategy or some other similar procedure to mimic that header interaction.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution, I put in top of my code, these lines

```
var j = request.jar(); var request = request.defaults({jar:j});
```

jar - If true, remember cookies for future use (or define your custom cookie jar;